# How to recover an I2C bus when SDA is stuck low? Edit: SDA line stuck high

Tags: i2c

See edit at the end of the message.

I have an Arduino in master mode connected via I2c to a slave, with 2k pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL. Sometimes the SDA line is stuck low, which causes my program to hang indefinitely.

How to recover from such a scenario?

Edit1: Since the SDA line is tied low the problem probably comes from the master. My guess is that the slave waits for the rest of the clock pulses that never come.

I'm not using the Wire library. I wrote my own implementation based on the AMmega328P datasheet.

```cpp
void TWIInit() {
  TWSR = 0x00;
  TWBR = 0x48; // SCL = 100khz
  TWCR = (1 << TWEN);
}

void TWIStart() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWEN);
  while ((TWCR & (1 << TWINT)) == 0);
}

void TWIStop() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTO) | (1 << TWEN);
  while (TWCR & (1 << TWSTO));
}

void TWIWrite(uint8_t data) {
  TWDR = uint8_data;
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
  while ((TWCR & (1 << TWINT)) == 0);
}
unsigned int TWIReadACK() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWEA);
  while ((TWCR & (1 << TWINT)) == 0);
  return TWDR;
}

unsigned int TWIReadNACK() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
  while ((TWCR & (1 << TWINT)) == 0);
  return TWDR;
}

unsigned int TWIGetStatus() {
  unsigned int statusOfRegister;
  statusOfRegister = TWSR & 0xF8;
  return statusOfRegister;
}

int TWISendBytes(uint8_t slaveAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t buf[], int numbBytes) {
  TWIStart();
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x08) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send address and Write bit
  TWIWrite(slaveAddr & 0xFE);
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x18) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send the register address
  TWIWrite(regAddr);
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x28) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send bytes
  for (int i = 0; i < numbBytes; i++) {
    TWIWrite(buf[i]);
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x28) {
      TWIStop();
      return 1;
    }
  }
  TWIStop();
  return 0;
}

int TWIGetBytes(uint8_t slaveAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t buf[], int numbBytes) {
  TWIStart();
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x08) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send address and Write bit
  TWIWrite(slaveAddr & 0xFE);
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x18) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send the register address
  TWIWrite(regAddr);
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x28) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // repeated start
  TWIStart();
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x10) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // send address and Read bit
  TWIWrite(slaveAddr | 0x01);
  if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x40) {
    TWIStop();
    return 1;
  }
  // get bytes
  for (int i = 0; i < numbBytes; i++) {
    if (i == (numbBytes - 1)) {
      buf[i] = TWIReadNACK();
      if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x58) {
        TWIStop();
        return 1;
      }
    } else {
      buf[i] = TWIReadACK();
      if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x50) {
        TWIStop();
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  TWIStop();
  return 0;
}
```

Edit2: The SDA line, and SCL, is held high not low as I first incorrectly assumed (I probably did something wrong when I measured it and thought it was low but anyway.) The problem was that the resistors I was using as pull-up resistors were in fact 1k not 2k. I changed them for 2k resistors and the problem disappeared.

Comment: First you'd have to figure out how it is happening.  If resetting the ATmega CPU doesn't clear it, it's probably not the Arduino's fault, and hence off-topic here.  Identification of the chip and traces captured with a cheap logic analyzer would be a help.  I recall a temperature/humidity chip that would jam the bus so badly if read in a certain mode that even removing power wouldn't clear it, you had to literally short the supply rail to ground.

Comment: write non blocking code

Comment: @ChrisStratton Resetting the Arduino clears it. And I realized that if the SDA line is low it is because the slave is waiting a clock from the master. So the problem must comes from my code. Also I'm not using the Wire library but instead wrote my own functions to handle the I2C communications. So it is likely there's a problem in the way I implemented it.

Comment: Is the problem gone when you do use the Arduino Wire library?

Comment: Ok so I found the issue. First the SDA line wasn't low but high. Second, I was using 1k pull-up resistors. So the actually issue was that the resistors prevented the slave or master to drive the line low. I changed them for 2k resistors and it stopped hanging. As an additional safety I added a watchdog to reset the Arduino if the program is hanging. @Jot The problem was the same with the Wire library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the pull-up resistors with 2k Ohm resistors. I thought I connected 2k Ohm resistors when in fact their value was 1k. So sometimes the SDA line couldn't be driven low due to the too strong pull-up resistors and that caused the hanging.

Comment: 4.7k is the more generally accepted value for the pull-ups. I have some screenshots [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=5#reply5) of the effect of different values for the resistors.